# NoReverseMatch at /category/clothes/ Django class based views

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, django-class-based-views, slug

I have a **django** project that is close to an e-commerce wesite in terms of functionality.

There are four pages **linked** to one another. First page displays **Categories**, 2nd **Subcategories**, 3rd **Product list** and 4th **Product detail** and I'm using **slugs** to navigate.

**ERROR**
`Reverse for 'product-list' with arguments '('', 'women-clothes')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<category_slug>[-\\w]+)/(?P<subcategory_slug>[-\\w]+)/$']`

Category to Subcategory linking code on the **category_list.html** is `<a href="{% url 'products-app:sub-category' category.category_slug %}">{{ category.name }}</a>` and on the **views.py**

```
class CategoryListView(ListView):
    models = Category
    template_name = 'products/category_list.html'
    context_object_name = "Category list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Returns all categories.
        """
        return Category.objects.get_queryset().all()
```

and **urls.py**

```
app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='categories'),
 url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', SubcategoryListView.as_view(), name='sub-category'),
 url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<subcategory_slug>[-\w]+)/$', ProductListView.as_view(), name='product-list'),
 url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<subcategory_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),]
```

The problem is linking **subcategory_list.html** to **product_list**. Since I need a **category_slug** and **subcategory_slug** to be pass to

`<a href="{% url 'products-app:product-list' category_slug subcategory_slug %}">{{ object.name }}</a>`.

I don't know how to implement this logic to using cbv. I want to pass **category_slug** since it is from a **Category model** and querying from **Subcategory model**. 
**views.py**

```
class SubcategoryListView(ListView):
    """
    Browse all products in the sub-catalogue.
    """
    model = Subcategory
    template_name = 'products/subcategory_list.html'
    context_object_name = "Sub-Category list"
    category_model = Category

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Returns all sub-categories.
        """
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, category_slug = self.kwargs.get('category_slug'))
        return Subcategory.objects.filter(category = self.category)
```

**category.html** which works.

```
    {% for category in object_list %}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <a href="{% url 'products-app:sub-category' category.category_slug %}">{{ category.name }}</a>
        <p>{{ category.category_slug }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

**subcategory.html**

```
        {% for object in object_list %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <a href="{% url 'products-app:product-list' object.category_slug object.subcategory_slug %}">{{ object.name }}</a>
         <p>subcategory_slug:{{ object.subcategory_slug }}</p>
        </div>
       {% endfor %}
```

How can get **category_slug** and pass it in the above **view** so as I can iterate on them on the template?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see what this has to do with CBVs. You haven't shown much of your template, but presumably you are iterating over subcategories and want to link to the individual list page for that subcategory. So, you just need to pass the slug and the category slug for the current subcategory in your loop.

This would be easier if you showed the rest of your template and your models, but assuming `object` is the subcategory, with a field called "subcategory_slug`, and the SubCategory model has an FK to Category:

```
<a href="{% url 'products-app:product-list' object.category.category_slug object.subcategory_slug %}">{{ object.name }}</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this error.
**Changes**

**views.py**

```
class SubcategoryListView(ListView):
    """
    Browse all products in the sub-catalogue.
    """
    model = Subcategory
    template_name = 'products/subcategory_list.html'
    context_object_name = "Sub-Category list"
    category_model = Category

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Returns all sub-categories.
        """
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, category_slug = self.kwargs.get('category_slug'))
        return Subcategory.objects.filter(category = self.category)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns self.category_slug needed 
        on the subcategory_list.html as a
        one of the {% url %} slug params.
        """
        context = super(SubcategoryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['category_slug'] = self.kwargs.get('category_slug')
        return context
```

On the **subcategory_list.html** i changed **object.category_slug** to **category_slug**.

**subcategory_list.html**
`<a href="{% url 'products-app:product-list' category_slug object.subcategory_slug %}">{{ object.name }}</a>` .